# Wifi connect api level 30+

Tags: java, wifi, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkRequest;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSpecifier;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import com.getcapacitor.Bridge;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WifiService {
    private static final int REQUEST_WIFI_SETTINGS = 1;
    private static String TAG = "WifiService";
    private static final int API_VERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    private PluginCall savedCall;
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    Context context;
    Bridge bridge;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> wifiAddNetworkLauncher;

    public void load(Bridge bridge) {
      this.bridge = bridge;
      this.wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.bridge.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      this.connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.bridge.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      this.context = this.bridge.getContext();

      wifiAddNetworkLauncher = bridge.registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Network suggestion added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("WifiService", "Network suggestion added successfully");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to add network suggestion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("WifiService", "Failed to add network suggestion");
            }
        }
      );
    }
    public void connect(PluginCall call) {
        // ...
        this.savedCall = call;
        String ssid = call.getString("ssid");
        String password = call.getString("password");
        boolean isHiddenSsid = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> existingSuggestions = wifiManager.getNetworkSuggestions();
            Log.d("existingSuggestions", "existingSuggestions " + existingSuggestions);

            boolean suggestionExists = false;
            for (WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion : existingSuggestions) {
                if (suggestion.getSsid().equals(ssid)) {
                    suggestionExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "suggestionExists " + suggestionExists, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (suggestionExists) {
                WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                        .setSsid(ssid)
                        .build();

                NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                        .build();

                networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected to Wi-Fi network: " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("WifiService", "Connected to Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUnavailable() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to connect to Wi-Fi network: " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("WifiService", "Failed to connect to Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);

                    }
                };

                connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connecting to Wi-Fi network: " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("WifiService", "Connecting to Wi-Fi network: " + ssid);
            } else {
                ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

                // WPA2 configuration
                suggestions.add(
                        new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                                .setSsid(ssid)
                                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                                .build()
                );

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("android.provider.extra.WIFI_NETWORK_LIST", suggestions);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Adding network suggestion...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("WifiService", "Adding network suggestion...");

            }
        } else {
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
            wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
            int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
            if (networkId != -1) {
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Connecting to Wi-Fi network...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("WifiService", "Connecting to Wi-Fi network...");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to add network configuration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("WifiService", "Failed to add network configuration");
            }

        }
    }

    public void disconnect(PluginCall call) {
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnecting from Wi-Fi network...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("WifiService", "Disconnecting from Wi-Fi network...");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("WifiService", "Wi-Fi is not enabled");
        }
    }
}
```

Making custom native capacitor plugin for connecting to wifi on api level 30+. Can someone help me with some questions? In the connect function i want to find out if the wifi network was already added to suggested list previously and just to connect to it. However, wifiManager.getNetworkSuggestions() returns empty list, but i can see that the network was saved... And also my disconect function doesn't work at all(( Can't understand what i'm doing wrong... Maybe there is another way to reconect to wifi spot

Permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```